# Fetching Cassandra Table Rows using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am facing the issue in connecting to cassandra using spark Repl..
Scala version 2.11,spark vesrion 1.6,cassandra version 3.0. When entering into spark shell I am using:

```
spark-shell --jars spark-cassandra-connector-1.6.0-s_2.10.jar
```

I'm trying to connect to cassandra using the following steps

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
 import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

sc.stop
val conf = new parkConf(true)
.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host",   "localhost")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val table = sc.cassandraTable("testtb", "words")
```

I'm getting the error when executing in the spark shell...

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnectorConf$
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:188)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.SparkContextFunctions.cassandraTable$default$3(SparkContextFunctions.scala:52)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:38)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:43)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:45)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:47)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:49)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:51)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:53)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:55)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:57)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:59)
at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:61)
at $iwC.<init>(<console>:63)
at <init>(<console>:65)
at .<init>(<console>:69)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at .<init>(<console>:7)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at $print(<console>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
at   rg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding the following command line option 
spark-shell --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.6.0-M1-s_2.10
this will work

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem when you mix-up Scala 2.10 and 2.11. If you have spark compiled with 2.11 you need to do get the 2.11 JARs (if they exist, otherwise move back to 2.10)

`spark-shell --jars spark-cassandra-connector-1.6.0-s_2.11.jar`